# change js code with jquery after dom loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting some resource with some js code inside.

the js code:

```
var trackurl = function(url){
   ga("send", "event", "outbound", "click", url, 
       {"hitCallback":function () {
              document.location = url;
       }
});
```

that js code is disabling the `target="_blank"` by setting `document.location = url`.

is it possible to remove `document.location = url` with jquery?

I dont have access to original js code of this resource

Comment: Could you research further, how exactly is that js code inside feed is disabling the target="_blank" in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I'm understanding:

you have like

```
<a class="classwith_alldata" href="/some-link" onclick="myfunction(); return false;" target="_blank"></a>
```

so you want to change js inside the `<a>`

```
$(function(){
   //$('.classwith_alldata').removeAttr('onclick');
   $('.classwith_alldata').('on', 'click', function(){
       myfunction();
      ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Worst-case scenario, the external third-party js is doing `$('[target]').removeAttr('target')`

Comment: almost, but i dont want to completely remove it, rather change it e.g. by removing only ``return false;`` from it.

Comment: @JoeFrambach not really. i will update my code in a sec